# The Code that's not a Code

Tags: cipher

What sentence do the following paragraphs encode?

Look lad. Light looms lad. See light shows. Silly silly shows. See.

Lately seven lemurs sang. La la la. Like seven skylarks. Stupidly.

Sit somewhere. Slice some sausages.

Send loaves. Lotsa sandwich loaves soon. Limes. Some sour lozenges. Some leeks. Some large sauerkraut sausages. Some long sauerkraut sausages. Like sandwich length long.

Shoot leopards.

Lets stop lighting socks. Stop stop. Stop lighting long socks. Stop stop stop stop. Stop. Someone lit socks.

Lucy says. Lie lie lie. Loudly.

Someone lurched.

Loud singers like shouting. Ludicrously loud long. Loud singers shouting. Shhhhhhh.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is

> MORSE CODE IS ACTUALLY A CIPHER NOT A CODE

which is encoded as

> morse code, obviously. Starting with L gives - and S gives .

Comment: Yessir. But why S and L in particular?

Comment: Short and Long :-)

Comment: Long and short indeed.